# PyCharm pip installs fail, RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

Tags: python, pycharm

I recently tried to use PyCharm and had trouble installing packages to a fresh virtual environment. I can't seem to get any packages to install. Here is the error I get in trying to execute "pip install numpy":

RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

DEPRECATION: --no-install, --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are deprecated.  See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.
Downloading/unpacking numpy
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\setup.py) egg_info for package numpy
    Running from numpy source directory.

```
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
```

Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy
    Running from numpy source directory.
    non-existing path in 'numpy\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    non-existing path in 'numpy\f2py': 'docs'
    non-existing path in 'numpy\f2py': 'f2py.1'
    F2PY Version 2
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib', 'C:\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

```
openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\mikejseay\\fresh\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\mikejseay\\fresh\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\mikejseay\\fresh\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\mikejseay\\fresh\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\mikejseay\\fresh\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1603: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\mikejseay\\fresh\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1612: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1615: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
lapack_opt_info:
openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\mikejseay\\fresh\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Users\\mikejseay\\fresh\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1505: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\mikejseay\\fresh\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1516: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1519: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Inumpy\core\src\private -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -Inumpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\PC /Tc_configtest.c /Fo_configtest.obj
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO _configtest.obj /OUT:_configtest.exe /MANIFESTFILE:_configtest.exe.manifest
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.obj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\setup.py", line 251, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\setup.py", line 243, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 62, in run
    r = self.setuptools_run()
  File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
    return distutils_install.run(self)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 39, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 153, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 164, in build_sources
    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
  File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 299, in build_library_sources
    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
  File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources
    source = func(extension, build_dir)
  File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 686, in get_mathlib_info
    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
Complete output from command C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\mikejseay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\mikejs~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-lkxc9u-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\include\site\python2.7:
Running from numpy source directory.
```

non-existing path in 'numpy\distutils': 'site.cfg'

non-existing path in 'numpy\f2py': 'docs'

non-existing path in 'numpy\f2py': 'f2py.1'

F2PY Version 2

blas_opt_info:

blas_mkl_info:

libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib', 'C:\']

NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:

libraries openblas not found in ['C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib', 'C:\']

NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib', 'C:\']

NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:

libraries satlas not found in ['C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib', 'C:\']

NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib', 'C:\']

NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:

libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib', 'C:\']

NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1603: UserWarning:

```
Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

the ATLAS environment variable.
```

warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.**doc**)

blas_info:

libraries blas not found in ['C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib', 'C:\']

NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1612: UserWarning:

```
Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

the BLAS environment variable.
```

warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.**doc**)

blas_src_info:

NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1615: UserWarning:

```
Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
```

warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.**doc**)

NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\lib': 'benchmarks'

lapack_opt_info:

openblas_lapack_info:

libraries openblas not found in ['C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib', 'C:\']

NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_mkl_info:

mkl_info:

libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib', 'C:\']

NOT AVAILABLE

NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib

libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info

NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:

libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib

libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info

NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib

libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info

NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:

libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib

libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\

libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info

NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1505: UserWarning:

```
Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

the ATLAS environment variable.
```

warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.**doc**)

lapack_info:

libraries lapack not found in ['C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\lib', 'C:\']

NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1516: UserWarning:

```
Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

the LAPACK environment variable.
```

warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.**doc**)

lapack_src_info:

NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1519: UserWarning:

```
Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
```

warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.**doc**)

NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

warnings.warn(msg)

running install

running build

running config_cc

unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options

running config_fc

unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options

running build_src

build_src

building py_modules sources

creating build

creating build\src.win32-2.7

creating build\src.win32-2.7\numpy

creating build\src.win32-2.7\numpy\distutils

building library "npymath" sources

No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils

customize GnuFCompiler

Could not locate executable g77

Could not locate executable f77

customize IntelVisualFCompiler

Could not locate executable ifort

Could not locate executable ifl

customize AbsoftFCompiler

Could not locate executable f90

customize CompaqVisualFCompiler

Could not locate executable DF

customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler

Could not locate executable efl

customize Gnu95FCompiler

Could not locate executable gfortran

Could not locate executable f95

customize G95FCompiler

Could not locate executable g95

customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler

customize IntelEM64TFCompiler

Could not locate executable efort

Could not locate executable efc

don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Inumpy\core\src\private -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -Inumpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\PC /Tc_configtest.c /Fo_configtest.obj

Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO _configtest.obj /OUT:_configtest.exe /MANIFESTFILE:_configtest.exe.manifest

Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

failure.

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.obj

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\setup.py", line 251, in

```
setup_package()
```

File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\setup.py", line 243, in setup_package

```
setup(**metadata)
```

File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup

```
return old_setup(**new_attr)
```

File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup

```
dist.run_commands()
```

File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

```
self.run_command(cmd)
```

File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

```
cmd_obj.run()
```

File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 62, in run

```
r = self.setuptools_run()
```

File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run

```
return distutils_install.run(self)
```

File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run

```
self.run_command('build')
```

File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

```
self.distribution.run_command(command)
```

File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

```
cmd_obj.run()
```

File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 39, in run

```
old_build.run(self)
```

File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run

```
self.run_command(cmd_name)
```

File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

```
self.distribution.run_command(command)
```

File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

```
cmd_obj.run()
```

File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 153, in run

```
self.build_sources()
```

File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 164, in build_sources

```
self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
```

File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 299, in build_library_sources

```
sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
```

File "C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources

```
source = func(extension, build_dir)
```

File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 686, in get_mathlib_info

```
raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
```

RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

---

Cleaning up...
Command C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\mikejs~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-lkxc9u-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\mikejseay\fresh\include\site\python2.7 failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\mikejseay\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\mikejseay\pip\pip.log

Comment: Mike - Did you ever solve this? I am having a similar problem on a variety of linux distros.

Comment: You need to install a Windows SDK